# React Native ArcGIS REST solve route

Tags: rest, react-native, routes, arcgis

I have created a routing network, which is published on ArcServer, for my institution. I want to create a mobile app with React Native, be able to take onpress coordinates as stops, pass them into the REST service and generate/show the route, ideally with directions.

The closest one example that I found is https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions. Is there anyway I replace google map service with my own?

Answer (score 0):

A feature of `react-native-maps-directions` *– of which I'm the author of –* is that you can override the `directionsServiceBaseUrl`, which defaults the one by Google.

```
<MapView initialRegion={…}>
  <MapViewDirections
    origin={origin}
    destination={destination}
    directionsServiceBaseUrl="…"
  />
</MapView>
```

Note that – for now – the output between Google's service and your services must be quite similar.